# Rotate a BitmapImage in c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, bitmapimage, storagefile

I'm experiencing some trouble with BitmapImage here. I have a WP8.1 app in which I can take photo, preview it and upload it. The preview is well displayed, good rotation and size but the problem is that, to upload it, I pass the byte[] corresponding to the storageFile wich is a big and not so well oriented picture.. I would like to rotate and shrink the storageFile BEFORE getting the byte[] from it.

Here is the snippet I use to preview/take/convert the picture :)

```
//Récupère la liste des camèras disponibles
    private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredCamera)
    {
        DeviceInformation deviceID = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desiredCamera);

        if (deviceID != null) return deviceID;
        else throw new Exception(string.Format("Camera of type {0} doesn't exist.", desiredCamera));
    }
    //Initialise la caméra
    async private void initCamera()
    {
        //Récupération de la caméra utilisable
        var cameraID = await GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
        //Initialise l'objet de capture
        captureManager = new MediaCapture();
        await captureManager.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
            {
                StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
                PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview,
                AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
                VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id
            });

        var maxResolution = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Aggregate((i1, i2) => (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width ? i1 : i2);
        await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, maxResolution);
    }
    //Évènmenet pour le bouton de prise de photo.
    async private void previewpicture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Si la prévisualisation n'est pas lancée
        if (EnPreview == false)
        {
            //On cache les élèments inutilisés.
            tfComment.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            vbImgDisplay.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            //On met la prévisualisation dans le bon sens.
            captureManager.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
            //On charge la prévisualisation dans l'élèment de l'image de la fenêtre.
            capturePreview.Source = captureManager;
            //On rend la prévisualisation possible.
            capturePreview.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            //Démarre le flux de prévisualisation
            await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();
            //On précise que la prévisualisation est lancée.
            EnPreview = true;
            //On change le label du bouton
            previewpicture.Label = "Prendre photo";
        }
        //Si la prévisualisation est lancée
        else if (EnPreview == true)
        {
            //Créer le fichier de la photo depuis la mémoire interne de l'application
            StorageFile photoFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("myFirstPhoto.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            //Récupère la photo avec le format d'encodage décidé.
            await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), photoFile);

            // we can also take a photo to memory stream
            InMemoryRandomAccessStream memStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpegXR(), memStream);
            //Debug.WriteLine(memStream.ToString());
            //Récupère l'image dans un objet image qu'on peut mettre dans le container d'affichage
            BitmapImage bitmapToShow = new BitmapImage(new Uri(photoFile.Path));
            //Met l'image dans le container d'affichage
            imgDisplay.Source = bitmapToShow;
            vbImgDisplay.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform() {CenterX = 0.5, CenterY = 0.5, Angle = 90 };
            //Cache la previsualisation
            capturePreview.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            //Arrête le flux de prévisualisation
            await captureManager.StopPreviewAsync();
            //rend visible les composants
            tfComment.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            vbImgDisplay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            //Converti l'image en tableau de byte
            photoByte = await GetByteFromFile(photoFile);
            //Précise qu'on est plus en prévisualisation
            EnPreview = false;
            previewpicture.Label = "Prévisualiser";
        }
    }
    //Converti un storageFile en Byte[]  
    private async Task<byte[]> GetByteFromFile(StorageFile storageFile)
    {
        var stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync();

        using (var dataReader = new DataReader(stream))
        {
            var bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
            await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
            dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

            return bytes;
        }

    }
```

Thx in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use the Lumia (Nokia) Imaging SDK to rotate the image, it's much easier.

You can get them here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumiaImagingSDK/2.0.184

And you can rotate the image like this:

```
using (var filterEffect = new FilterEffect(source))
{
    // Initialize the filter and add the filter to the FilterEffect collection to rotate for 15 degrees
    var filter = new RotationFilter(15.0);

    filterEffect.Filters = new IFilter[] { filter };

    // Create a target where the filtered image will be rendered to
    var target = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);

    // Create a new renderer which outputs WriteableBitmaps
    using (var renderer = new WriteableBitmapRenderer(filterEffect, target))
    {
        // Render the image with the filter(s)
        await renderer.RenderAsync();

        // Set the output image to Image control as a source
        ImageControl.Source = target;
    }

    await SaveEffectAsync(filterEffect, "RotationFilter.jpg", outputImageSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //this method will rotate an image any degree
   public static Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap image, float angle)
    {
        //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image

        double radius = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(image.Width, 2) + Math.Pow(image.Height, 2));

        Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap((int)radius, (int)radius);

        //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
        using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap))
        {
            //move rotation point to center of image
            graphic.TranslateTransform((float)radius / 2, (float)radius / 2);
            //rotate
            graphic.RotateTransform(angle);
            //move image back
            graphic.TranslateTransform(-(float)image.Width / 2, -(float)image.Height / 2);
            //draw passed in image onto graphics object
            graphic.DrawImage(image, new Point(0, 0));
        }
        return returnBitmap;
    }
```